# Strange MVC Referencing Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC solution that was 3.0.0.0 but I'm upgrading it to 4.0.0.1. I've upgraded the System.Web.Mvc reference (in the reference folder) and it's dependencies, e.g. updated System.Web.WebPages from 1 to 2.

When I build the project it builds without issue, however when I run the project I get the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1705: Assembly 'MobileScanner, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

P.S. Using VS2010, and .Net 4.0

Comment: Do you have multiple projects? If so, did you upgrade MVC in all of them that reference it?

Comment: Do you have the right versions in package.config?

Comment: `MobileScanner` uses MVC 4.0 and your references version still shows version 3.0 , Did you update your system mvc dll as well?

Comment: Somewhere you still have MVC v3. Find it and update it. Application CheckAsm is useful for this.

Comment: check the version of the mvc dll here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\`

Comment: @Reddy Yes The first thing I did was remove the reference to 3 and put the new reference to 4 in - manually.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck MVC was not added to this project using nuget, it was simply installed on the machine and referenced manually.

Comment: Did you check the path I mentioned?

Comment: @PaulZahra if you don't install using nuget the dll file in your machine (system) will still be the old one. So you would have to manually update it in your system as well. But while installing from Nuget it will update this path as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help but I fixed it.

The issue was that there were still references to MVC 3 and some of it's (old) dependencies (System.Web.Razor) in the root web.config and then again in the Views/web.config... once updated it worked a treat.